# How to edit datasource in IReport?

Tags: ireport

I have created a JDBC DB datasource in IReport 5.1.0  design.

Now I want to edit the datasource.

How to edit datasource in IReport? I  don't  find Edit datasource menu in IReport . Where is it ?

Comment: Via the Button **Modify** in *Conncections/ Datasources* dialog

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the root (report) and press edit query